# Fourier conjugate problem?

Tags: fourier-analysis

Do I need to use conjugation rules to show that $\overline{h(t)}=\hat{g}(t)$ and when $g(t)=\overline{\hat{h}(t)}$? Trying to prove parsevals identity with this one.

Edit: Something like this: $$\mathcal{F}g(t)=\mathcal{F}\overline{\hat{h}(t)}
=\overline{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\hat{h}(t)e^{-i2\pi vt}dt}=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\overline{\hat{h}(t)}e^{i2\pi vt}dv=\overline{h(t)}$$
Because the complex conjugate makes it the inverse fourier transform for formula? I think I can handle the Parsevals identity if this is the logic behind this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A notation that might make this easier:
$$
        g^{\wedge}(s) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}g(t)e^{-ist}\,dt,\;\;\;\; g^{\vee}(s)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}g(t)e^{ist}\,dt.
$$
For $L^{2}(\mathbb{R})$, one has $(g^{\wedge})^{\vee}=g$. In general, $\overline{g^{\wedge}}=\overline{g}^{\vee}$ and $\overline{g^{\vee}}=\overline{g}^{\wedge}$. It's a common and convenient notation because the order of conjugation can be swapped if you turn the $\vee$ or $\wedge$ upside down. For example, in your notation, $g=\overline{h^{\wedge}}$, and
$$
     \mathcal{F}g = g^{\wedge}=(\overline{h^{\wedge}})^{\wedge}=\overline{(h^{\wedge})^{\vee}}=\overline{h}.
$$

Comment: Hmmm we haven't used that kind of notation on our course, but that makes sense. What I wrote also makes sense yeah?

Comment: @ELEC: They're the same thing. I kept getting confused by the same things when I started with the transforms until I started using the hat-wedge notation. Just thought I'd pass it along as it was passed along to me.

Comment: You are missing a square root in the factor of the inverse transform. Does putting accents on the letters also work? $\overline{\check g}=\hat{\overline g}$, $\overline{\hat g}=\check{\overline g}$. Not really, looks rather small.

Comment: @LutzL: I corrected the missing square root. Thanks. Yes, going vertical makes complicated expressions too hard to read.